# Anaular2 typescript object typecasting

Tags: json, typescript, angular2-routing

Am trying to get `model object` from the json comes from `http response call`.

Below  `JSON` is the body part of `http response`,

```
{

"dataType": "RWSupplier",
"partyName": "Lifecare Pharmaceuticals",
"partyShortName": null,
"partySecondaryName": null,
"partySecondaryShortName": null,
"sortingName": "Lifecare Pharma",
"mailingName": null,
"entityType": "SP",
"partyType": "OG",
"partySubType": null,
"extPartyId": null,
"comments": null,
"prGenderType": null,
"prBirthDate": null,
"prSalutation": null,
"statusCode": null,
"lastUpdateDate": "2017-03-06T04:30:00.000+0000",
"lastUpdateUser": "RwAdmin",
"tinNum": "33450701833",
"cstNum": "790052 dt. 4/4/2001",
"stNum": null,
"dlNum1": "5324/MIII/20B",
"dlNum2": "5205/MIII/21B",
"limitList": [ ],
"tagList": [ ],
"buId": "510",
"partyId": "SP001011001" }
```

i created the interface for above `JSON` data as follows,

```
export interface SupplierBrief {
dataType: string;
partyId: string;
buId: string;
partyName: string;
statusCode: string;
comments: string; }
```

As i dont need all the properties which are served from the rest call.

Since am planning to omit unnecessary properties from caching and reduce memory by removing such properties. For that i wrote my service as given blow.

```
return this.http.request(path, requestOptions).map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json() as models.SupplierBrief;
        });
```

But still the `SupplierBrief` contains all the properties which are returned by rest call.

I may be misunderstood the concept of model objects, Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

nah, you'll have to do the work. Create a new object, set the values, return it.